# best way to remove nested key with in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary something like this so

```
acc = ["key1", "key_", "four"]

dict = {"key1": "something", "key_": "something2", "three": {"four": "remove this", "five": "dsadsdsas"}}
```

Need to remove all this particular key from json which is mentioned in acc variable.

```
{key: value for key, value in dict.items() if key not in acc}
```

this doesn't remove the "four" key

So what can I do here?

Comment: You could look into doing it recursively.

Comment: don't name variables with reserved keywords: `dict etc.`

Answer (score 4):

The reason that it does not work like you would is that the keys in your dictionary are: `key1`, `key_` and `three`. `three` is not in `acc` and the value of `three` is kept. That this value is a dictionary is not tested and therefore not used when you filter your dictionary.

Therefore you have to use recursion to check if the item in your dictionary is itself a dictionary. If that is the case, also filter this "dictionary inside a dictionary".

For example:

```
# do not use dict, this is a built-in function.
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
d = {"key1": "something", "key_": "something2", "three": {"four": "remove this", "five": "dsadsdsas"}}

def filter_dict(d: dict, acc: list = ["key1", "key_", "four"]) -> dict:
    new_d = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in acc:
            continue
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            new_d[key] = filter_dict(value)
        else:
            new_d[key] = value
    return new_d

filter_dict(d)

>>> {'three': {'five': 'dsadsdsas'}}
```

This example will return an empty dictionary when all keys are inside `acc`. How to deal with those kind of dictionaries is up to you, you can change this line to deal with empty dictionaries:

```
new_d[key] = filter_dict(value)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you first test if key not in acc? Otherwize you would get an empty dict for dict values when the acc request key deletion

Comment: Yes you are right, if the sub-dict is behind a key which should be removed that sub-dict should also be removed. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and its *`object_pairs_hook`* (used on decoding phase):

```
import json

stop_k = ["key1", "key_", "four"]
d = {"key1": "something", "key_": "something2", "three": {"four": "remove this", "five": "dsadsdsas"}}
filtered = json.loads(json.dumps(d), object_pairs_hook=lambda pairs, stop_k=stop_k: \
    dict((k,v) for k, v in pairs if k not in stop_k))
```

---

```
{'three': {'five': 'dsadsdsas'}}
```